# Pandas: extract index and column after processing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a `DF1` that resembles this:

```
    A            B
X   BLA, FOO     XY, ZY, DW     
Y   BAR, BLA     FOO, DW
Z   UVH, DD      RATM,QOTA
```

Each element of the DF is a string with the following structure: `BLA, FOO, BAR, ...`. I would like to reshape this into a `DF2` based on the single elements, converting it to an association of `X` and `A`:

```
       A        B
BLA    X, Y
FOO    X        Y
XY              X
...
```

As you can see, each element of `DF1` shows the association between index and column. Is there a more practical way to do this than to read row by row and column by column? Or, how do you get the `index` and `column` from `pd.DF.applymap()`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

- for each column create `DataFrame` by `split` and Series by `stack`
- reshape for Series by `stack` - all splitted values are in one column
- convert `MultiIndex` to columns by `reset_index`
- group by duplicates pairs for unique `MultiIndex`, aggregate `join` for duplicates
- reshape by `unstack`
- data cleaning - columns and index name by `rename_axis`

---

```
df1 = (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',\s+', expand=True).stack())
       .stack()
       .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
       .reset_index(name='val')
       .groupby(['val','level_1'])['level_0']
       .apply(', '.join)
       .unstack(fill_value='')
       .rename_axis(None)
       .rename_axis(None, 1))
```

---

Thanks, [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565549/pandas-extract-index-and-column-after-processing-values/46565668#comment80084951_46565668) for similar solution:

```
df1 = (df.stack()
        .str.split(', ', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='val')
        .groupby(['val','level_1'])['level_0']
        .apply(', '.join)
        .unstack(fill_value='')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df)
         A     B
BAR      Y      
BLA   X, Y      
DD       Z      
DW          X, Y
FOO      X     Y
QOTA           Z
RATM           Z
UVH      Z      
XY             X
ZY             X
```

---

```
df1 = (df.stack()
        .str.split(', ', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index=0, 
                     columns='level_1', 
                     values='level_0', 
                     aggfunc=','.join, 
                     fill_value='')
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, 1))
```

Comment: Wow ultra speed

Comment: `df.stack().str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().reset_index().groupby([0,'level_1'])['level_0'].apply(', '.join).unstack(fill_value='')` without needing first `apply`

Comment: And, using pivot, `df.stack().str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().reset_index().pivot_table(index=0, columns='level_1', values='level_0', aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='')`

Comment: My brain is not following this. But it returns the correct result. Could you add some small comments/edits to help us layman-pandas users understand?

Comment: @MattR - Sure, give me some time.